# Thread synchronization problem

Tags: multithreading, qt, list

I use Qt and C++. I have a list of threads (`Qlist<QtThread>`).

I try to synchronize them. All threads calculate some values. And I want to take them.

Have you any ideas? thank a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [finished()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qthread.html#finished) signal of a thread to execute a slot when your thread finishes executing.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit broad, but Qt has a lot of documentation on different thread synchronization methods.

The base of the docs is at [Threading Support in Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/threads.html). The specific part you should find the info in is the [Synchronizing Threads](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/threads-synchronizing.html) section. It lists the various mutex, locks, semaphores, wait conditions that are available in the Qt framework.

The documentation for all these classes has example usage code. Also have a look at the [Threading and Concurrent Programming Examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/examples-threadandconcurrent.html), you'll probably find what you're after in there.